# Is there any joke exist in Campbell's words?

Tags: meaning, jokes

> Wallace: We'll make spears. Hundreds of them. Long spears, twice as
> long as a man.
>
> Hamish: That long?
>
> Wallace: Aye
>
> Hamish: Some men are longer than others.
>
> Campbell: **Your mother been telling you stories about me again**.
>
> (They laughs)

Is there any joke exist in Campbell's words?

Source: Braveheart (1995)

Comment: A long man could mean a tall man, or a man with a long penis. That is the joke.

Comment: Also, a joke in that Hamish's mother would know the length of Campbell's penis.

Comment: The joke here is that Campbell is definitely considered a person who is inclined to delay doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Campbell has exploited the duality of meaning in Hamish's words (sometimes referred to by the pseudo-French expression 'double-entendre') to make an innuendo about the length of his own penis. It is also meant as a humourous insult to Hamish's mother.

> Hamish: Some men are longer than others.
> Campbell: Your mother been telling you stories about me again.

The men are talking about the length of *spears*, but Hamish's exclamation that "some men are longer than others" could in isolation refer to the length of men's penises, as sometimes in English a man's penis is referred to as if referring to the whole person. Campbell's quip that Hamish has heard these words from his own mother about Campbell is a suggestion that Campbell has had sexual intercourse with Hamish's mother.

Comment: Also, Hamish uses "longer" to mean "taller" when talking about how "some men are longer than others" - which might not be obvious.